# Prove a measure is ergodic

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{B})$ be a measurable space, Then assume $T:X\to X$ is uniquely ergodic, i.e. there exists a unique probability invariant measure $m$. Then $m$ is ergodic.

Do you have any ideas?

Which definition of ergodicity shall I have to verify?

Comment: There is a theorem that tells you, that the ergodic measures are the extremal points of the so called "Choquet-simplex", which is nothing else but the set of all $T$-invariant measures. Knowing this theorem, you immediatley get ergodicity of the measure. The proof of the theorem itself is not that hard to do.